# How to add a scroll pane to my frame

Tags: java

I would like to add a scroll pane to the right side of my frame in a gui. Could somebody 
 give me the code?  I do not know if it is necessary to import something else besides javax.swing.  Below is the main . I hope you could read it.  Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;


public class School {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Test t= new Test();
        JFrame f = new JFrame ("Calculus");

        f.add(t);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize (530, 700);
        f.setVisible (true); 

    }
}
```

Comment: every thing you need is in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: I made a typo. It is new not mew.

Comment: Salah, thank you for your help. I tried what you suggested and it did not work.  I want a scroll pane on the frame not a  small  text area. could you tell me where to find the information. Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `JPanel` then added it to `JScrollPane`, then add this `JScrollPane` to your `JFrame`

**For Example:**

```
JFrame f = new JFrame ("Calculus");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
Test t= new Test();
panel.add(t);// add the component you want to be scrolling to the scroll pane.
JScrollPane scrollFrame = new JScrollPane(panel, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
f.add(scrollFrame);
```

Comment: Salah, thank you so much, you are a genius. The scroll pane shows up perfectly but at the bottom of the gui, not at the right. Could you tell me how to put the scroll pane to the right? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Salah, I would like the scrollpane vertical, not horizontal.

Comment: you can do that as above.